# Regex to match a period but not if there is a period on either side (Java)

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a regex that will match a period character, ONLY if none of that period's surrounding characters are also periods.

```
 Fine by me... leave!    FAIL

 Okay.. You win.     SUCCEED

 Okay. SUCCEED //Note here, the period is the last char in the string.
```

I was thinking do:

```
 [^\\.*]\\.
```

But that is just wrong and probably not at all in the right direction. I hope this question helps others in the same situation as well.

Thanks.

Comment: First of all, when you put an `*` in square brackets, it means that it's looking for a `*`.  (Or in this case, it's looking for a character that isn't `*`.)  If you're thinking that `*` means "zero or more of something", that's not true inside square brackets.

Comment: You may want "negative lookahead" and "negative lookbehind".  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html.

Comment: Could you clarify the question, in particular you have the second scenario succeeding, even though it has two periods, followed by some text, and then a final period. Is there some stipulation that if there is more than one set of periods in the target text, that it will only consider the last?

Answer (score 5):

You need to wrap the dot in negative look arounds:

```
(?<![.])[.](?![.])
```

I prefer `[.]` over `\\.`, because:

1. It's easier to read - there are too many back slashes in java literals already
2. `[.]` looks a bit like an X wing fighter from Star Wars ™

Comment: So does your second reason apply to any other characters?  :)  I'm thinking if I want to match the word "book", maybe I should use a regex like `b[o][o]k` because the `[o]` looks a little like a ... OK, it looks like a front-loading washing machine, which isn't cool at all, so never mind.

Answer (score 0):

That regex will still match any period that isn't preceded by another period.

`[^\.]\.[^\.]`  Takes care of both sides of the target period.

EDIT:  Java doesn't have a raw string like Python, so you would need full escapes: `[^.]\\.[^.]|^\\.[^.]|[^.]\\.$`

Comment: So my current regex expression was `\\.|\\?|\\!`  I attempted to add your expression:    `[^\.]\.[^\.]|\\?|\\!` but the expression doesn't quite work correctly. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Double up the backslashes in my expression.  The single backslash is a Python habit that doesn't work in Java.

Comment: But that doesn't work for your 3rd example `OKAY.` with a dot at the end of the string.

Comment: Good point, dev.null.  Should have stars in there to account for first/last character.

Comment: @SnoProblem Putting stars in there won't work.  If you say `[^\.]*\.[^\.]*, it will still match `a..b`.  The first `[^\.]*` matches `a`, the dot matches the first dot, the next `[^\.]*` matches _the empty string between the two dots_.  Sorry, but I don't think this is a valid solution.

Comment: @ajb -  If you look at my edit, I realized it was incorrect as soon as I typed it.  The correct regex is in my edit.

Comment: I see--but it's hard to read your edit because it's split over multiple lines.  That's why I didn't recognize that it was a solution.  Also, the way you worded it implied that you were just fixing the backslashes,which isn't true because you changed the whole thing, but that made me miss it.  Also, it won't match a one-character string with just a dot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative look ahead and look behind or this alternative regex:

```
String regex = "(^\\.[^\\.]|[^\\.]\\.[^\\.]|[^\\.]\\.$)";
```

The first alternative check the beginning `^` of the string (if it can start with a dot), the second looks for any dot inside and the third looks for a dot at the end of the string `$`.